# Is it good practice to use an instance method also as a static method?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have the following constructor `URL` (**Figure 1**) to help explain my question. The method `isValidUrl` takes an optional parameter `optUrl`. By default the instance property `url` is used. It is however overridden by the argument `optUrl` if the argument is set.

I'm not sure if this is good software engineering practice.

**Figure 1:**

```
function Url(url) {

    this.url = url;

    this.isValidUrl = function (optUrl) {
        var url;

        // Questionable pattern
        if (typeof(optUrl) === 'undefined') {
            url = this.url;
        } else {
            url = optUrl;
        }

        // 1. call: 'http://www.example.com'
        // 2. call: 'http://www.exampl2.com'
        console.log(url); 

        return url !== ''; // Very simple check
    }
}

var u = new Url('http://www.example.com');
console.log(u.isValidUrl()); // true
console.log(u.isValidUrl('http://www.exampl2.com')); // true
```

Comment: 1) it's still not a static method - an object is needed 2) I would do the check in the constructor and throw an exception... a Url object without a valid url doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I agree with 1). I also agree with 2) but my code above is just a simple example.

Comment: What could happen is that someday you don't know where that value comes from when you enter u.isValidUrl(). In such a simple example ofc you would still know but in more complex things it could lead you to wrong results/returns. I'd throw false if not valid url given like empty string/undefined

Answer (score 2):

First, I would make the isValid a static helper method in a UrlHelper or something.
If you only need the Url class for this method, I would avoid having a separate class and call directly the helper.

Something like:

```
function Url(){

}

Url.isValidUrl(url){
 if(!url) return false;

  return true; //add here code to check if url is valid 
}
```

If you do need the Url class for some extra logic, then you can call the method from the helper class.

As far as your question goes whether it is a good practice to override the instance property with the argument, my opinion is no. In your example above you are using your class both as an object (creating instances, calling methods on those instances) and as a utility class which doesn't have anything to do with a specific instance (at least in the example above).

Comment: If Url would have a thousand methods would you still have UrlHelper for static checks? I agree with your opinion in the last paragraph. In my case I'd probably remove the optional argument and only work with the url passed to the constructor.